# Managing Jenkins build from Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins

I have a set of Jenkins builds arranged to run one after another. Now, I would like to manage the builds, means start the build and provide the inputs etc, through java program (written in Eclipse), I know that it should be possible. What I am looking for some guide explaining the best way to set it up which makes my java program independent of jenkins installation. I mean that it would import the necessary jenkins/plugins jar to the eclipse and can run in any system without separately installing/configuring jenkins over there. 
If there is any instructions for that, please provide me. Appreciate your help...

Comment: Take a look at [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)... Since you want to implement in java, you can directly include the CLI jar and call it's methods if you want...

Comment: Thanks Codebender. Jenkins CLI seems to be good option but It would be  really helpful for me if I can get some example of its usage with java. Any suggestions or link would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Jenkins/Hudson connector](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector) that you can install into Eclipse. It gives a view of Jenkins servers where you subscribe to build jobs and initiate, monitor, etc.